# How to call custom function when closing popup window in OSX Cocoa Application using Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have two `ViewControllers` and a button which is drag-and-dropped from the first `ViewController` (source) to the second one (destination, popover). This connection is set as Popover Storyboard Segue.

How can I call a specific function in the source `ViewController` when the destination `ViewController` (popover) is being closed (clicked outside the popover)? Is there any standard view lifecycle method like `viewWillAppear` etc. for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `NSPopover` `delegate` to the source `ViewController`, then you get methods such as `popoverWillClose:` and `popoverDidClose:`.

There's also corresponding notifications (as standard with macOS controls), if you do not like using the delegate.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't knew about this protocol.